# Admin on Rest: How can we preserve a query param between

Tags: admin-on-rest

We have a need where 3 different menu items perform CRUD operations to the same resource ("assets"), but with just the `category_id` being different on **all** CRUD operations (until you press again a different menu item).

In order to do this, we introduced a query param, called `kind`, which is the only practical difference among these 3 links:

```
    <MenuItemLink
        to={{
            pathname: '/assets',
            search: stringify({page: 1, perPage: 25}),
        }}
        primaryText="Assets" 
        onClick={onMenuTap} 
        leftIcon={<AssetsIcon />} 
    />

    <MenuItemLink
        to={{
            pathname: '/assets',
            search: stringify({
                page: 1,
                perPage: 25,
                kind: 'printers'
            }),
        }}
        primaryText="Printers"
        onClick={onMenuTap}
        leftIcon={<AssetsIcon />}
    />

    <MenuItemLink
        to={{
            pathname: '/assets',
            search: stringify({
                page: 1,
                perPage: 25,
                kind: 'vehicles'
            }),
        }}
        primaryText="Vehicles"
        onClick={onMenuTap}
        leftIcon={<AssetsIcon />}
    />
```

Through the following code, the List fetches records only for these assets:

// NOTE: 'parsedKind' is parsed grom query params with previous code, it gets one of these values: '' OR 'printers' OR 'vehicles'

```
    <List
        title={<TitleList location={props.location} />}
        {...props}
        filters={<AssetFilter location={props.location} key={parsedKind} />}
        perPage={15}
        filter={{cat_id: dbIds[parsedKind]}}
        sort={{field: 'name', order: 'ASC'}}
        actions={<OurCustomListActions parsedKind={parsedKind} {...props} />}
        key={parsedKind}
    >
```

In order for this to work we had to customize the "actions" with custom Buttons, so that the `parsedKind`is following through. For example, the `CreateButton` now needs a prop `ourQuery`:

```
   <FlatButton
        primary
        label={label && translate(label)}
        icon={<ContentAdd />}
        containerElement={<Link to={`${basePath}/create?${ourQuery}`} />}
        style={styles.flat}
    />
```

I have 3 questions here:

1. This was a tedious work (all buttons have been customized) and I wonder if there was another solution to cover this need.
2. Still, the "SaveButton" causes headaches, because it uses a `handleSubmitWithRedirect` function that comes from `props` and the parameter is just the name of the view ('list' for example). So how can I add the query param on the final URL there? I used an ugly `setTimeout` to do this after 2 seconds (`window.location.hash = window.location.hash + '?' + this.props.ourQuery;`) but obviously this is very wrong. The `DeleteButton`is also problematic because it redirects to a subview.
3. Using the above approach I get `NaN-NaN from 19` in the List pagination. Why? Can this also be solved somehow?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think your best bet would have been to simply create three resources: `Assets`, `Vehicles` and `Printers`. 
Than in your restClient/dataProvider, create logic to route these three resources to the `assets` endpoint with the correct `parameter`. I simple middleware would suffice, something in the line off:

```
// MyAssetResourceMiddleware.js
export default restClient => (type, resource, params) => {
     switch(resource){
        case 'Assets':
        case 'Vehicles':
        case 'Printers':
          return restClient(type,'assets',{...params,kind:resource});
        default: 
          return restClient(type,resource,params);
     }    
}
```

And wrap your provider with it

```
<Admin dataProvider={MyAssetResourceMiddleware(dataProvider)} .../>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure what I would do with "kind" then.
You mean I should use it as "filter" inside the restClient? I would have to change the code there?

Comment: Yes, you can decide for yourself; add it to the query params or whatever.

Comment: Is "react-admin" ("admin-on-rest") halted? I see no activity for 8 days (no commits, answers to issues, etc.).

Comment: React-admin is maintained by marmelabs, so I expect them to be on holiday. I'll bet the commits and responses will be back soon.

Comment: How may I contact you if we need some help?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? I am not from marmelab. Questions can be asked on SO.

Comment: How about this case?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49289320/how-can-all-crud-actions-of-a-resource-by-linked-to-a-particular-foreign-key
Thanks!