# How can all CRUD actions of a resource by linked to a particular foreign key?

Tags: admin-on-rest, react-admin

Version: `Next` (react-admin)

Resources `Classes` and `Students`.

"Students" has a foreign key to "Classes": `class_id`.

So, in the `List` of `Classes` we have for each row (class) a button "View/Edit Students of Class".

When we click on this button, we have this code:

```
<Button
  label={'View/Edit Students of Class'}
  onClick={(e) => {
    localStorage.setItem('classId', record.id);
    history.push({
        pathname: 'students',
        search: stringify({
            page: 1,
            perPage: 25,
            sort: 'createdOn',
            order: 'DESC',
            classId: record.id,
        }),
    })
  }}
>
```

The idea is that we need somehow to get a 'classId' value in all CRUD operations of the 'Student', so that we filter by 'classId' in List and use this classId as a disabled field in CREATE.

I tried 2 ways: `localStorage` or `query params` as you can see in the code.

But these are not good, not working as expected (query params are lost when CREATE redirects, etc.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should link to a *filtered* list, something like

```
<Button
  label={'View/Edit Students of Class'}
  onClick={(e) => {
    localStorage.setItem('classId', record.id);
    history.push({
        pathname: 'students',
        search: stringify({
            page: 1,
            perPage: 25,
            sort: 'createdOn',
            order: 'DESC',
            filter: { classId: record.id },
        }),
    })
  }}
>
```

This is done in the demo, see https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest-demo/blob/master/src/categories/LinkToRelatedProducts.js